# How do I get the id of a mouse when multiple mice are connected in x11?

Tags: c, x11

according to [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Multi-pointer_X) article it is pretty easy to have multiple mouse pointers in x11. But when processing the event as an [`XEvent`](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/structures.html) in a program, how do it get the id of the virtual pointer or virtual keyboard?

Comment: You need to use XInput extension.